# Autoprotolysis Constant of Water

Tags: water, aqueous-solution

My chemistry textbook states that $[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}] = K_w$ in all aqueous solutions, which we know of as $K_w$. However, I was wondering why this was true. The textbook states that it is true because $K_w$ is an equilibrium constant, but why are we allowed to assume that the other ions take no part in this reaction?

To clarify further, consider the following reaction
$$\ce{HCl + H2O (l) <=> H3O+ + OH- + Cl- }$$
Of course this isn't balanced, but why doesn't the hydrogen ion on the left affect the equilibrium constant?

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook is correct, the $K_\mathrm{w}$ expression is as follows:
$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}]=1.0\times10^{-14}$$

Since for every $\ce{OH-}$ there must be one $\ce{H+}$ ($\ce{H+}$ in water is synonomous with $\ce{H3O+}$) the mol ratio is 1:1, if moles are equal the molarities are equal. I'm going to substitute $x$ in for both
$$K_\mathrm{w}=[x][x]=[x]^2=1.0\times10^{-14}; x= 1.0\times10^{-7}.$$

So the molarity of $[\ce{OH-}]$ and $[\ce{H3O+}]$ are both $1.0\times10^{-7}$ That's a really really low amount, small enough to ignore.

However, a lot of reactions (especially in Organic Chemistry) you'll see a negative ion, for example, $\ce{Cl-}$ pulling the $\ce{H+}$ off of a water. So when $[\ce{OH-}]$ or $[\ce{H3O+}]$ are needed, water can be torn apart to make it.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll be sure to learn Latex before posting again. Sorry you had to go through and correct my post.

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy when my edits are appreciated. For me it is no problem, and I am just trying to help. Don't worry too much about it, learn from the edits others make on your posts and you'll do just fine. If you want to play a little, you can use the [sandbox](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3077/4945) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

!!Bing!! !!Bing!! !!Bing!! Congratulations - You're thinking like chemist!!

Your textbook has stated an oversimplification which isn't really true. Let's define $\ce{K_{w}}$ based on concentrations as: $$\ce{K_{w} = [H^+][OH^{-}]}$$

(1) The value of $\ce{K_{w}}$ changes with temperature.

(2) $\ce{K_{w}}$ changes with pressure.

(3) $\ce{K_{w}}$ depends on the total ionic strength of the solution, which includes spectator ions.

See Wikipedia article "Self-ionization of water" section ["Dependence on temperature, pressure and ionic strength."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature.2C_pressure_and_ionic_strength)

The "real" relationship at any temperature and pressure is given in the [goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00532.html) as noted by Martin: $$\mathrm{K^{*}_{w} = 1.00 \times 10^{-14} = a(H^+) a(OH^-)}$$

where $\mathrm{a(H^+)}$ and  $\mathrm{a(OH^-)}$ are the activities of $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{OH^-}$. In dilute solution the activity of an ion can be approximated by its concentration. A "dilute solution" is dilute enough if a linear relationship holds between concentration and activity. In general this would be 0.1 N or less.

Comment: Wait sorry, I made a false conclusion off of what the chemistry textbook said. It says $[H_3O^+][OH^-] = K_w$ always, but thank you for taking note of this error.

Comment: The self-ionization constant of the reaction $\ce{HA + B <=> A- + HB+}$ is certainly defined as $K_\mathrm{w} = a(\ce{A-})\cdot a(\ce{HB+})$ at any given temperature or pressure. See [goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00532.html)). OP makes no statement about the book contradicting that. It just simplifies that instead of activities the concentrations are used, and that it is true for any aqueous solution (which is a stretch).

Comment: Trying to be a smartass I tripped over my own feet. I think I have it fixed correctly now.

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry but now you contradict yourself. Your points 1-3 are absolutely correct. The value of $K_\mathrm{w}$ is only $1.0\times10^{-14}$ for standard conditions. The definition, i.e. product of the activities is generally valid for any pure phase of water. (And maybe you'd try to ping me, so that I can remove my vote)

Comment: @Martin - マーチン - Don't know if this will ping you are not. Did you miss that I defined $\mathrm{K_w}$ as depending on absolute concentrations, and $\mathrm{K^{*}_{w}}$ as depending on activities?

Comment: It did ping. You write:  The "real" relationship at any temperature and pressure is given in the goldbook as noted by Martin:
$\mathrm{K^{*}_{w} = 1.00 \times 10^{-14} = a(H^+) a(OH^-)}$. This is incorrect, as $1.0\times10^{-14}$ is the value for $25~^\circ\mathrm{C}$.